# $T$ is a complete propositional theory with $\Gamma \subset T$ iff $T=\mathrm{Th}(V)$ for some model $V$ of $\Gamma$.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm reading *Fundamentals of Mathematical Logic* by Peter G. Hinman, and I'm stuck with a corollary in section 1.4 about propositional theories:

**Corollary 1.4.13** For any set $\Gamma$ of sentences and any propositional theory
$T$ , the following are equivalent:

(i) $T$ is a complete propositional theory with $\Gamma \in T$ (a complete extension
of $\Gamma$);

(ii) $T = \mathrm{Th}(V)$ for some model $V$ of $\Gamma$.

It is a corollary to the theorem that if $V$ is a truth assignment, then $\mathrm{Th}(V)$ is a complete and consistent propositional theory, and $V$ is the unique model of this theory. I'm having trouble obtaining a model $V$ of $T$ in the implication (i) => (ii). I tried to first prove that $T$ is consistent but was stuck. Any ideas?

Some definitions:

**Definition 1.4.5** A set $T$ of sentences is a **propositional theory** iff it is closed
under tautological consequence — that is, for all sentences $\phi, T \vDash \phi \implies \phi \in T$.

**Definition 1.4.8** For any set $\Gamma$ of sentences,

(i) $\Gamma$ is consistent or **satisfiable** iff Γ has at least one model; otherwise, Γ
is inconsistent or unsatisfiable;

(ii) $\Gamma$ is **complete** iff for every sentence $\phi$, either $\phi \in \Gamma$ or $\neg\phi \in \Gamma$, but not both — that is, $(\neg \phi) \in \Gamma \iff  \phi \notin \Gamma$; otherwise Γ is incomplete.

**Definition 1.4.10** For any truth assignment $V$ , the **theory of $V$** is the set $\mathrm{Th}(V) = \{\psi : V (\psi) = T\}$.

Truth assignments are defined to respect connectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $T$ is complete, for each propositional variable $P$, exactly one of $P$ and $\neg P$ is in $T$.  So this gives you a truth assignment: let $V$ be the truth assignment that says a propositional variable is true if it is in $T$ and false if its negation is in $T$.  Now you can use the fact that $T$ is closed under tautological consequence to show that in fact $T=Th(V)$.

Comment: How do we know that $V$ defined this way respects connectives? Is it possible that $\Gamma = \{p_0 \land \neg p_0\}$ and still $T$ is complete?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that something later in the section is needed for this.

1. There is only one inconsistent propositional theory $T$, namely the set of all sentences. In particular, for each sentence $\phi$, we have $\phi, \neg \phi \in T$.
2. As a result, a complete theory is consistent. In fact, a theory is complete iff it is maximally consistent. It has a unique model $V$, which satisfies $V(\phi) = 1$ iff $\phi \in T$.

Now $\mathrm{Mod}(\Gamma) = \mathrm{Mod}(\mathrm{Th}(\Gamma))$, we can easily prove the claim.